# How to show more child elements in debugger's variable popup message?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, popup

I'm working with **[glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/)** in **Visual Studio 2013**, and there's big inconvenience in how debugger shows the variable values. If some element has more than 3 children, debugger shows only the first 3 of them. For example, If I have 4x4 matrix (**glm::mat4**), and I want to see its content during debugging, I only see the first 3 elements of each column - please, check the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJxTh.png

As you can see, I don't see the 4-th element, though there are kilometers of free space to the right. The same rules are applied to the **Autos** and **Locals** windows, though there's more than enough white space to show 4 or even 5 elements (well, I need only 4). I have to individually expand each column to see its 4-th element, and it's really annoying.

I know it is pretty specific problem, but maybe there is some way to make **VS** show more child elements by default?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the visual studio visual debugger by editing the autoexp.dat file.

Here is a great tutorial that I used to learn how to edit it. http://www.idigitalhouse.com/Blog/?p=83